# What is RouterView in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

When I do the Vue quickstart and it creates a HelloWorld application, I see that App.vue line 20 contains this line:

```
<RouterView />
```

I can't find any documentation for RouterView. It seems odd that a quickstart / tutorial would include an undocumented tag. I do see router-view, is that the same thing?

Comment: yes its the same thing https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-view you can use `<RouterView />` or `<router-view />` or `<router-view></router-view>` as with all vue components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Vue docs for [**Component Registration** > **Name Casing**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing):

> When defining a component with PascalCase, you can use either case when referencing its custom element. That means both `<my-component-name>` and `<MyComponentName>` are acceptable. Note, however, that only kebab-case names are valid directly in the DOM (i.e. non-string templates).

So `<RouterView />` is the same as `<router-view />`.

Answer (score 5):

The RouterView or router-view component is used to display the component or template that corresponds to the current route.

Source: vue-router.d.ts

```
/**
 * Component to display the current route the user is at.
 */
export declare const RouterView: new () => {
    $props: AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & VNodeProps & RouterViewProps;
    $slots: {
        default: (arg: {
            Component: VNode;
            route: RouteLocationNormalizedLoaded;
        }) => VNode[];
    };
};
```

Here is a webpage detailing how to use the RouterView component: [How to Use Vue Router's router-view Component](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/vue/router-view#/)

After doing some of my own experimenting, I created a vue app (with Vue Router), I found that my components were not being displayed even if I was at the specified route. After adding the RouterView component to my App.vue template, I was able to see the view that was specified by the route.

Edit:

I'd suggest looking through the following tutorial:
[Create your own Vue.js Router](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/creating-your-own-router/). After I created my own router I can now understand why this component is present. The component will render the component that the route specifies, therefore, when the route changes the component rendered will change.

Comment: correction: <router-view> displays the component or template that corresponds to the current URL...

Comment: Hi, where should i put <router-view/>? Is it best practice to put it in App.vue? Or it can be putted in anywhere such as Home.vue?? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ZiSang, that depends on what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at [router-view](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-view). It is a case by case basis where you put it.